# Apache to NGINX proxy configuration redirect rules

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy

I searched some topics regarding Apache to Nginx conversion, but I was unable to find one that relates to Proxy configuration rules. I'm a complete newcomer to server languages, but I'm in desperate need to migrate my website to the new hosting providers (that is running on Nginx).

I need to redirect all traffic from www.impactteachers.com/teach to application.impactteachers/teach.

In Apache:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On



<Proxy http://application.impactteachers.com:8080/teach/>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Proxy>



ProxyPass /teach/ http://application.impactteachers.com:8080/teach/
ProxyPassReverse /teach/ http://application.impactteachers.com:8080/teach/
```

I have tried @John suggestion (Thank you for leading me in the right direction) but still no luck and I changed t he code to what I found here http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache

So this is where I'm at:

```
location /teach {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

   proxy_pass              http://application.impactteachers.com:8080;
   proxy_redirect          off;
}
```

Still nothing, can you guys help me out?

Comment: And have you try anything?

Comment: Hi @AlexeyTen thank you for your quick response I have tried using Apache to Nginx converters like http://winginx.com/en/htaccess but because I need to send this code to my hosting company I can't actively test. Sorry if this didn't help clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested.. In your server block:

```
location /teach {

        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;

        proxy_pass              http://application.impactteachers.com:8080;
        proxy_redirect          off;

    }
```

Comment: Hi @John thank you for your answer I will pass this on and let you know how it went. Thank you for your shout.